# Is it possible to establish socket communication between Windows 7 and Linux machine over LAN?

Tags: networking, sockets

I have connected a Linux machine and a Windows machine via LAN cable. Both machines are not connected to any network. Is it possible to establish a socket communication between these machine? If yes, how?

Comment: Of course it is possible. You need a server on one end and a client on the other. Apart from that your question is too broad.

Comment: @DavidPostill In normal scenario where both the machines are on same  network creating a sever at one and client at other will work but I am not sure If both machines are not connected to any network just connected to each other via LAN cable, the same will work.

Comment: You are responsible for configuring the 2 network cards so that they have have IP addresses that are in the same local network.

Comment: @DavidPostill Do you have any idea how can I do that on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 machine?

Comment: Give them both fixed IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Step by step, including a couple of pitfalls to avoid:

- First, by LAN cable I assume you mean a twisted pair Ethernet cable. It is not clear whether you used a hub/switch or simply connected the two ends of one cable to two different computers; if it's the second option, you will need a [crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable).
- Next, you will need to assign an IP address to each interface: @DavidPostill already commented that you need static IPs for that, if you do not have a DHCP server in either machine.
- Then, before attempting to communicate via sockets ([OSI layer 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Interfaces)), it would be a good idea to test the lower network layers: e.g. try pinging each machine first.
- If all this worked, now you just need an application to listen to a port (the server) and another that connects to it (the client): each one of these connection will have a network socket associated with it.